# 'IEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Relational'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

After migration from Entity Framework Core 2.2 to version 3.0, I get this error:

> Error CS1061
>   'IEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Relational' and no accessible extension method 'Relational' accepting a first argument of type 'IEntityType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
// Method that returns IEntityType
private static IEntityType GetEntityType(Type type, DbContext appDbContext)
{
    var entityType = appDbContext.Model.FindEntityType(type);
    return entityType;
}

// Get table name dynamically
public static string GetTableName(this Type type, DbContext appDbContext)
{
    var entityType = EfExtensions.GetEntityType(type, appDbContext);
    var mapping = entityType.Relational();
    var tableName = mapping.TableName;
    return tableName;
}
```

So what is the EF Core 3 way for achieving the same result?

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. Answer can be found elsewhere. See above. In short change ..Relational().TableName into GetTableName().